# Minor alignment issue in the tag info page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, design, tag-wiki

In any tag's info page, the **Tag Info** box is overlapped with the above horizontal line. Adding some space in between them or adding margin-top to the tag info div will improve the page design.

For example, in the [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info) tag info page.

**Current UI:**

> [image: current]

**Expected UI:**

> [image: expected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed. Extra `border-top` is gone.